# Cannot convert value of type to expected argument type when the type is an associated type

Tags: swift

Here is the **swift 4** code:

```
protocol BarProtocol {
    associatedtype Bar
    var bar:Bar? {get set}
}

class FooClass : BarProtocol {
    //typealias Bar = (String) -> ()
    typealias Bar = (String)
    var bar: Bar?
}

func configFooClass<T:BarProtocol>(fooClass:inout T, bar:T.Bar) {
    fooClass.bar = bar
}
func setupFooClass(fooClass:inout FooClass, bar:FooClass.Bar) {
    configFooClass(fooClass: &fooClass, bar: bar)
}

var fooClass = FooClass()
var barString = "barString"
//let barAction:(String) -> () = { text in
//    print(text)
//}

setupFooClass(fooClass:&fooClass, bar:barString)
print(fooClass.bar) // print: Optional("barString")
```

So far so good, it will print "Optional("barString")" in console. The associatedtype in class FooClass in String type now, so it can store string value "barString".

But if I change this code to :

```
protocol BarProtocol {
    associatedtype Bar
    var bar:Bar? {get set}
}

class FooClass : BarProtocol {
    typealias Bar = (String) -> ()
//    typealias Bar = (String)
    var bar: Bar?
}

func configFooClass<T:BarProtocol>(fooClass:inout T, bar:T.Bar) {
    fooClass.bar = bar
}
func setupFooClass(fooClass:inout FooClass, bar:FooClass.Bar) {
    configFooClass(fooClass: &fooClass, bar: bar) 
// Error here: Cannot convert value of type '(String) -> ()' to expected argument type '_.Bar'
}

var fooClass = FooClass()
var barString = "barString"
let barAction:(String) -> () = { text in
    print(text)
}

//setupFooClass(fooClass:&fooClass, bar:barString)
//print(fooClass.bar)
setupFooClass(fooClass:&fooClass, bar:barAction)
fooClass.bar!("lalalalala")
```

Actually, I just change the FooClass's associatedtype from String to (String) -> (), it will have an arror: Cannot convert value of type '(String) -> ()' to expected argument type '_.Bar'

I don't understand, it seems closure can pass as parameter of function. But why 'String' type work well but '(String) -> ()' does not?

Answer (score 0):

It seems adding a @escaping can solve this problem...

```
func setupFooClass(fooClass:inout FooClass, bar:@escaping FooClass.Bar) {
    configFooClass(fooClass: &fooClass, bar: bar)

}
```